# How to fetch data from js files (more than one files) in jsr223 sampler or else

Tags: jmeter

I want to add two different js for authentication, currently i am using jsr223 sampler & done the following steps,
1. added both js in /bin folder.
2. used load() method in jsr223 sampler for loading the js but output is unable to load the js. please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure you have `javascript` selected as JSR223 Sampler Language
2. JavaScript [`load()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/Shell#load.28.5Bfilename.2C_....5D.29) only "loads" the given script, you will need to invoke the relevant function(s) manually

For example, you have the following `hello.js` file:

```
function sayHello () {
    log.info('Hello');
}
```

In order to load it and call `sayHello()` function you need the next JSR223 Sampler configuration:

- Language: `javascript`
- Script:

  ```
  load('hello.js')
  sayHello()
  ```

  Demo:

  [image: JMeter execute JavaScript]

Remember that JavaScript engine performance might be a big question mark when it comes to high loads so rather than importing JavaScript libraries I would rather recommend re-implementing the same functionality using [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) language.

See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) guide for more details.

Comment: where can i drop hello.js file in lib or bin folder.

Comment: If you want to use the relative path - use `bin` folder (or where you launch JMeter from), if not - place it wherever you want and use full path